# Protobuf without serialization

Tags: interface, protocol-buffers

As the name suggests I was wondering if it makes sense to use Protobuf without the requirement of having to serialize the data in any form at the moment (might change in future). I mean to use them purely as data structures to pass Information from one function to the other, all executed in the same address space. Or do you feel it may be an Overkill and see other alternatives.

Backgroud:
I have to design a lib that implements certain interfaces. At the moment, my collegues have implemented it using several functions taking arguments .. 
Example:

```
void readA(int iIP1, int iIP2, Result& oOP)
void readB(std::string iIP1, Result& oOP)
void readC(std::vector<int> iIP1, Result& oOP)
```

I want to change this and provide just one interface function:

```
void ReadFn(ReadMsg& ip, ReadResult& res);
```

And the data structures are defined in Protobuf as below ..

```
message ReadMsg {
enum ReadWhat {
 A = 0;
 B = 1;
 C = 2;
}
message readA {
  int32 iIP1 = 1;
  int32 iIP2 = 2;
}
message readB {
  string IP1 = 1;
}
message readC {
  repeated int IP1 = 1;
}

oneof actRead {
  readA rA = 1;
  readB rB = 2;
  readC rC = 3;
}
}
```

It offers many advantages over traditional interface design(using functions), with very Little effort from my side. And it will be future proof should these components be deployed as Services in different processes/machines (ofcourse with additional implementation). But given that Protocol Buffers strength is their serialization Features, which I do not make use of at the moment, would you choose to use them in such trivial Tasks ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It can make sense to group function arguments into a `struct` if there are many of them. And it can make sense to combine your `readA`, `readB` and `readC` functions into a single function if they share a lot of common parts.

What doesn't, however, make sense in my opinion is introducing a separate `.proto` file and a protobuf dependency if you are not going to use it for serialization. Similar features for grouping data into reusable structures already exist in most languages. And when you use the built-in features of the language, all the code remains in the same place and is easier to understand.

Comment: I agree and infact simple 'C' stuctures were my initial thought, but again I want to avoid direct data access, then I wanted to avoid big memory footprint of each message (internally the ReadMsg should hold either readA, readB, or readC, but not all at the same time), etc. Given that Protobuf already comes with all the required infrastructure around it, this gradual inclination towards it. But yes, I still do not see a real strong reason why I should use it against simple structures. Thanks for commenting.